# How to display the value using formControlName in a label -angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I was looking for a non-input control, like span or label, that can be used with formControlName.

API structure:

```
{
 "id": "PO1",
 "supplierNote": "Other Notes4",
 "purchaseOrderProducts": [
  {
    "id": "prdt1"
    "quantity": 10,
    "unitPrice": 100,
    "totalTaxableValue": 100
  }
  {
    "id": "prdt2"
    "quantity": 7,
    "unitPrice": 30,
    "totalTaxableValue": 100
  }
]}
```

I used the below method.

```
  getControlLabel(type: string){
    return this.PurchaseOrderFormGroup.controls[type].value;
  }
```

To display the **supplierNote** ,I  used  the below code,

```
<label>{{getControlLabel('supplierNote')}}</label>
```

It displays it in both label and textbox. And its like below

[image]

But I am not able to display the **totalTaxableValue** in the label(It is in an array).

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz?

Comment: I tried more methods like purchaseOrderProducts.totalTaxableValue ,purchaseOrderProducts[0].totalTaxableValue etc.. Not even a single method works. Can anybody help me??

Comment: How to use this method for purchaseOrderProducts.totalTaxableValue

Comment: How does your form look like? We cannot guess how it looks like, therefore it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the totalTaxableValue by binding the a variable in the label like this.
First store the api values in a variable.
Then use that variable key values to bind to the value.
Eg.    ttV: string = apidetails.purchaseOrderProducts[0].totalTaxableValue;.

This way then you can bind the value to the label as  {{ttV}}